# DataTables: How do I disable row selection for editable columns

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I have a simple datable in which I have made one column (no. 4) editable using jeditable similarly to the example on the datatables.net:

```
oTable.$('td:eq(4)').editable(function(value, settings) { 
var valueOld = oTable.fnGetData(this);
if(valueOld != value) {
    alert("changed");
}
else { 
    alert ("unchanged");
}
    return(value);
}, 
{ 
type    : 'textarea',
submit:'OK'
});
```

I also want to be able to select a row by clicking on it (again as per the example on datatables.net):

```
$('#example tr').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
});
```

However, it does not make sense that the row is selected when the user clicks on column 4 of that row because that cell is editable.  How do I disable row selection when clicking on this editable column?

I am not using TableTools.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element that was actually clicked in the click handler function to make sure it was not the 4th column.

```
$("#example tr").click( function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if(!target.is(":nth-of-type(4)") {
        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this question was asked and answered when the older version was prevalent, for anyone using the current version, this works well:

```
select: {
  style:    'os',   //default but you have to specify it, no idea why
  selector: 'tr:not(.no-select) td'
}
```

Then manage which rows are unselectable by tacking the `no-select` class on them.

Via https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30597/prevent-row-selection

*Side note: don't know whether the style re-definition is still an issue. You can try w/o and see if the wheels come off.*